# Fetch data from local machine to browser

Tags: angular, plugins, google-chrome-extension, rdp

I'm just completed my first Angular project.
For my next one I need to do the following:

1. Fetch machine and user data to use in my Angular code
2. Open programs via browser with arguments

I understand that opening programs can be done with custom protocol handler.. but what if I also need to fetch data from local machine..

If I not mistaking that could be done by chrome extension but I'm not finding any tutorial for create that connection or how to connect the extension to my Angular project

For example: fetch os info and network info,
Open RDP connection (mstsc) with arguments

Did you know the best way to achieve that goal?

This is supposed to be app for business use so I don't care if I need to install something on the client PC..
Of course I will welcome another suggestion for accomplish that

Comment: You'll have to write a separate utility and invoke it from your extension via nativeMessaging, see the documentation.

Comment: You could also run a local http server that your app can talk to, but it would have to be always running in the background.

Comment: I have no problem to write separate utility and call it via nativeMessaging, with that said I steal need to call it from my Angular app and fetch some data back, and this is the part I don't find an answer to..